# One Bazel project produces binary and static library files, another similar project only produces binary files

Tags: c++, build, bazel, bazel-rules

I am attempting to learn Bazel so I've been using it to build very simple projects in order to understand how it works and some of the ins and outs of the tool.

Currently, I have 1 project (called Enigma) that builds a `main.cpp` file that relies on a couple of libraries I wrote (I wrote it this way to understand the Bazel rules better, in this particular project it doesn't really make sense to have these libraries, but I digress). When I run the build, I can check my `bazel-bin` directory and find:

1. a binary file produced by my `cc_binary` rule
2. a static library (*.a) file for one of the `cc_library` rules I implemented

This makes sense to me. I started a new project, `LinkedList` that I wanted to build just as a library. From some troubleshooting and research, I decided I needed a rule that depends on that `cc_library` rule in order for Bazel to actually build it, so I created another `main.cpp`. When I run the build, I only get a binary from my `cc_binary` rule, but no *.a files from my `cc_library` rule. I've examined both the `BUILD` files I have and cannot find anything glaringly different about them. Both projects' `WORKSPACE` files are empty and neither project has a `.bazelrc` file.

Here are the contents of my Enigma `BUILD` file (which produces `libsignal_converter.a` in the `bazel-bin` directory):

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_binary(
    name = "enigma",
    srcs = [ "main.cpp" ],
    deps = [ ":rotor", ":plugboard" ]
)

cc_library(
    name = "signal_converter",
    srcs = [ "signal_converter.cpp" ],
    hdrs = [ "signal_converter.h" ],
    includes = [ "." ]
)

cc_library(
    name = "plugboard",
    hdrs = [ "plugboard.h" ],
    includes = [ "." ],
    deps = [ ":signal_converter" ]
)

cc_library(
    name = "rotor",
    hdrs = [ "rotor.h" ],
    includes = [ "." ],
    deps = [ ":signal_converter" ]
)
```

Here are the contents of the `bazel-bin` directory of the Enigma project:

```
 _objs
 enigma
 enigma-2.params
 enigma.cppmap
 enigma.runfiles
 enigma.runfiles_manifest
 libsignal_converter.a
 libsignal_converter.a-2.params
 plugboard.cppmap
 rotor.cppmap
 signal_converter.cppmap
 tests.cppmap
```

Here is the contents of my LinkedList `BUILD` file, which only produces a binary:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library")

cc_binary(
    name = "dummymain",
    srcs = [ "main.cpp" ],
    deps = [ ":linkedlist" ]
)

cc_library(
    name = "linkedlist",
    hdrs = [ "node.h", "linked_list.h" ]
)
```

And here are the contents of the `bazel-bin` directory of the LinkedList project:

```
 _objs
 dummymain
 dummymain-2.params
 dummymain.cppmap
 dummymain.runfiles
 dummymain.runfiles_manifest
 linkedlist.cppmap
```

Just in case, I made sure to include my libraries in the `main.cpp` file and initialize an instance of each class. I get the typical "unused variable" warning, but aside from that it builds and runs as expected.

My question is why does my Enigma project produce *.a files but my LinkedList project does not?

How can I configure my build such that it produces *.a (or *.so) library files with or without a `cc_binary` rule that depends on them?

What I've tried:
At first, my LinkedList project `BUILD` file only contained a `cc_library` rule. I believe that Bazel was not building that target (despite me running `bazel build //src:linkedlist`) because no other rules depended on it and it was a library target (although I feel like I am wrong about that assumption). To remedy that, I created a `main.cpp` file with a `cc_binary` rule to accompany it. This seems to trigger a build of the `linkedlist` target, but I still do not see any library files in my `bazel-bin`. I would have expected it to produce a statically linked binary as well as the static library (*.a) files but all I get is the binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"plugboard"`, `"rotor"`, and `"linkedlist"` targets contain only header files. There are no files directly compiled in those libraries. Therefore, Bazel suppresses the creation of static archives for those libraries.

Comment: Ah I see. In the case of LinkedList, it is a templated class so there is no accompanying .cpp file. Can I explicitly ask Bazel to create a static archive for them? or would I have to "fake it out" by creating an empty .cpp file?

Comment: I tried creating a .cpp file that simply includes my header only implementations and that worked to create a static archive! Not sure if there is a more "bazel" way of doing it, but I got the result I was after. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I'm not sure what such a static archive is useful for?

Comment: This was mostly for my own understanding of how Bazel works. My imagined use case was a project that builds a shared or static library that can then be distributed and linked to in other projects. The actual functions of the source files here are arbitrary, I just wrote them as an exercise to use Bazel.